# Como criar uma barra de progresso dinâmica no R?

Tags: r, processo, progress-bar, java-processing

Para acompanhar o status do processamento em minhas rotinas utilizo as barras de progresso do pacote `pbapply`, mas não encontrei uma forma dinâmica de acompanhar mais de um processo. Para ilustrar o problema considerei uma lista contendo três elementos de dimensões diferentes e que se queira junta-los levando em conta o elemento em comum entre eles (ID):

```
 lista<-list(A=data.frame(ID=1:100, Med=rnorm(100,50,100)),
        B=data.frame(ID=1:50, Med=rnorm(100,50,50)),
        C=data.frame(ID=51:100, Med=rnorm(100,50,25)))

 result<-data.frame(ID=1:100,matrix(NA,nrow = 100,ncol = length(lista)))

 for(t in 1:length(lista)){
     local<-dim(lista[[t]])[1]
     for(t2 in 1:local){
         posilocal<-which(result$ID==lista[[t]]$ID[t2])
         result[posilocal,(t+1)]<-lista[[t]]$Med[t2]
     }
  }
```

Como posso criar uma barra de progresso que mostre a situação do processo, considerando a evolução de t e t2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é o ideal, mas você pode tentar fazer assim, usando o pacote [`progress`](https://github.com/gaborcsardi/progress).

```
library(progress)
total <- sum(sapply(lista, function(x) dim(x)[1]))
pb <- progress_bar$new(total = total)
for(t in 1:length(lista)){
  local<-dim(lista[[t]])[1]
  for(t2 in 1:local){
    posilocal<-which(result$ID==lista[[t]]$ID[t2])
    result[posilocal,(t+1)]<-lista[[t]]$Med[t2]
    Sys.sleep(3/100)
    pb$tick()
  }
}
```

Primeiro calcular o tamanho total do loop e depois fazer uma barra que o percorra dessa forma.

Parece ser mais complicado colocar uma barrinha que apareça para cada processo. Essa é uma limitação do RStudio pelo que eu entendi. Ler [essa discussão](https://github.com/gaborcsardi/progress/issues/26) pode ajudar a entender. Parece que o suporte a múltiplas barras está nos planos do pacote `progress`.